# Enable CORS on WCF Service. Get HTTP 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, iis, cors

I am trying to enable CORS on a WCF service. When I try to send a request from my client, the request is sent using the `OPTIONS` verb. I always get a `HTTP 405: Method not allowed` error

If I try using Fiddler and create the same request with the `POST` verb the response seems to be correct.

I have tried to remove `webDAV` with the help of the tutorial 
http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/ but it doesnt seem to work.

I have updated my WCF to enable CORS referring to the tutorial http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html. I am not sure what is going wrong. The response seem to have the CORS header

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS: I did not want to make the question very big and confusing. If you would like to look at my config be let me know and I can share it

Comment: Rather then just add the required headers for the preflight request and ensuring the OPTIONS message isn't blocked, it would be better to implement CORS in WCF. It's a shame that OOTB WCF only comes with a behavior that's compatible with ASP websites. http://www.productiverage.com/wcf-cors-plus-json-rest-complete-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link http://praneeth4victory.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/405-method-not-allowed/:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
               HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
               HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
               HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
               HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
               HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
              }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But this till does not help. Atleast now I am not getting the HTTP 405. I get a HTTP 200 but no response comes back. The response Content-Length is always 0

Comment: @Ron I have the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Ron Nevermind. What I ended up doing was moving Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the web config.