# WCF Service JSON Post data using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, wcf

Having problem when using POST using JSON in ASP.NET. Kindly check my code when I used POST. Is there's something wrong when javascript code?

Exact error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)
>   localhost:99/Service1.svc/api/updtelogin.json XMLHttpRequest
>   cannot load localhost:99/Service1.svc/api/updtelogin.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'localhost:1110' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

IService

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "api/updtelogin.json")]
    UpdateUser updteUser(RequestData rData);
```

RequestData

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

Service.svc

```
    private UpdateUser updateuser(RequestData rData)
    {
        return updteUser(rData);
    }

    public UpdateUser updteUser(RequestData rData)
    {
        var data = rData.details.Split('|');            

    }
```

And this is my javascript from ASP.NET

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnChange").live("click", function () {
        var test = {};
        test.uname = "admin";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:99/Service1.svc/api/updtelogin.json',
            data: "{rData:" + JSON.stringify(test) + "}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d.uname);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you have two applications:

- localhost:99 - wcf service
- localhost:1110 - web application calling your wcf service

This violates ["same origin policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) for your ajax request because of different port.

Here you have instruction how to add CORS headers to WCF service: [Enable CORS on WCF Service. Get HTTP 405: Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544669/enable-cors-on-wcf-service-get-http-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: What I'm getting now is Bad request POST localhost:99/Service1.svc/api/updtelogin.json 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: It looks like deserialization problem:
 data: "{rData:" + JSON.stringify(test) + "}"
does not correspond to your RequestData type:
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string details { get; set; }
}